# Where can I find a good example GAsyncQueue usages between process and thread

Tags: c++, c, gtk, glib

Beyond explanation of [GAsyncQueue](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html#GAsyncQueue)   I cannot find anything  on how to use this data structure, examples, patterns. I am trying to use to as a IPC mechanism between thread and the main process.

Can someone demonstrate it?

Thanks

Comment: Assigned a little bounty here, would go for a good usage sample, that is better that a Liferea source. Topicstarter, do you have one to show?

Comment: Nope... no idea, actually.  I haven't worked with GAsyncQueue in over 1.5 years.